# Overwrite/append to multiple-value column in R data.frame

Tags: r

I have a data frame which contains a column in which I want to put multiple values (it can have a different amount of values per record).

I'm trying to append data to it using a for loop but it keeps giving the error:

```
Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, 1, "piet", value = c(1, 2)) : 
replacement has 2 rows, data has 1
```

Is it impossible to overwrite/append to this column?
Small example code:

```
a = data.frame(piet=numeric())
a[1,'piet'] = c(1)
a[1,'piet'] = c(1,2) # this throws the error
```

I realise there are better ways than using a for loop, but my data is spread out somewhat randomly over multiple .csv files (of which some have overlapping records, whose results I'm trying to combine here).

Comment: The data.table package requires less obscure syntax for list columns: `aDT = data.table(piet = list()); rbind(aDT, list(piet = list(list(8,9))))`. In general, for your "lots of CSVs" problem, I would read them all into a list, and then use `rbindlist`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, looks pretty useful. I'll take a look some time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok this is really weird but it works using `list(c())` (thanks @Frank) and a very specific coding format:

```
a = data.frame(piet=list()) #initialize data frame
a[1,'piet'] = '' # create first row
a$piet[c(T)] = list(c(1,2,3)) # overwrite with list
a$piet[c(T)] = list(c(4,5,6)) # overwrite with new list
a$piet[c(T)] = list(c(unlist(a[1,'piet']),8,9)) # append to existing list
```

final contents of a:

```
> a
           piet
1 4, 5, 6, 8, 9
```

Note that the `a$piet[row selection]` is mandatory as well as using `list(c())`!

Comment: What is  `c(T)` supposed to do?

Comment: c(T) is a vector with booleans that indicates which rows you want to have selected. In my case I only have 1 row. You can leave [c(T)] out if you don't want to perform row selection.